# PostgreSQL using to_char with floor

Tags: postgresql, to-char

Ok I am converting from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I am having trouble with some to_char.

```
CASE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(to_char(floor(_FloatValue)))))
    WHEN 1 THEN '0' || LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(floor(_FloatValue))))) || ':'
    ELSE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(FLOOR(_FloatValue))))) || ':'
```

I'm getting this error

```
   [2015-11-10 15:40:20] [42883] ERROR: function to_char(double precision) does not exist
   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
   Where: PL/pgSQL function formatfloattohoursminutes(double precision) line 10 at RETURN
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: 1) Show sql server code 2) Tell what it do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to left pad with zeros:

```
select to_char(_FloatValue, '09.99');
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE